# change Parent Menu color, when we click on childMenu using CSS and html

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, scss-mixins

```html
<li class="btn-group" mdbDropdown>

  <a mdbDropdownToggle id="ParentId">
    <i class="nav-item"></i> MainMenu <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a id="chaildId1" routerLinkActive="class-nav_mi" routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact:true}" [routerLink]="['/logs']">Menu-1</a>
      <a id="chaildId2" routerLinkActive="class-nav_mi" routerLinkActiveOptions="{exact:true}" [routerLink]="['/reports']">Menu-2</a>
  </div>

</li>
```

when we click on child Menu, i want change color of Parent Menu from child Menu color
Apply Child Menu color to Parent Menu, after click on child Menu

[image: refernce image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [brand new `focus-within` sudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

For consistency, you will also want to use `:hover`

```css
.btn-group:focus-within > a > .nav-item,.btn-group:hover a .nav-item {

/*apply hovering/focus colors*/
}
```

For onclick colors, you'll have to use JavaScript

Edit:You just changed a tag to Angular, not familiar with that